# Could anyone explain me about forming core mode and defected mode in photonic crystal fiber?

Tags: fiber-optics, photonics

I need some information about upper mode and lower mode in photonic crystal fiber sensor.
What conditions should be provided for core mode and defected mode to be formed?

[image]

Comment: I would browse the RP Phonics Encylcopedia. For example, https://www.rp-photonics.com/passive_fiber_optics1.html